# Align button left in a Bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making some grid elements in Bootstrap 3. On the picture with the airplane, I am trying to align the button in the same position as on the picture with the lion, but only when the viewport is below `< 768px`.

[See the demosite here](http://vouzalis.dk/stackoverflow.html).

When the viewport is `> 768px` I position the button with the following class:

```
.bottom-right {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 8px;
   right: 16px;
}
```

How can I change the position of the button without affecting any other buttons on the grid? There is many buttons there is using the class `bottom-right`

This is how the end result should look like:

[image: Demo picture]

I have cut away so much code as possible there is not relevant for the question

```css
body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }
    /* Set width between grid elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }
    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Position of buttons in a single grid element */
    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }
    .header-textbox-bottom-left {
      position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }   
    .card-content {
      display: flex;
      padding: 30px 0px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    .card-content__info {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      left: 3em;
      position: relative;
      /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    }
    
    .card-content__info > h4 {
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 5px 0 !important;
    }
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        }
        .index-content .card img {
        height: 100%
      }

       .card-content__info {
           flex-direction: column;
           left: 0;
        }

      .card-content {
          flex-direction: column;
          left: 20px;
          position: relative;
          align-items: inherit;
      }
      /* Position button on banner with textbox */
      .header-textbox-bottom-left {
        position: static;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      }    
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .card {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .card-content h4,
      .card-content p,
      .card-content span {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .card-content a {
        float: right;
      }
      .index-content .card h4,
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 0 20px 15px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .card-content-textbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        /*right: 0;*//* top position on right*/
        margin: 15px;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 91%
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding top bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://www.sardiustours.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/lion-1118467_1920-Copy.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content-textbox flexbox-column">
                        <h4>BMW & HEADLINE 2018</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                        <div class="inner-wrapper header-textbox-bottom-left">
                          <button class="btn btn-success">Read More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/bf/cf/87bfcfb36780c0fec472d8d301be7a1c.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-content__info">
                          <h4>HIGH SERVICELEVEL AND QUALITY</h4>
                        <span>Book a meeting and let's find a solution</span>  
                        </div>         
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success bottom-right">Read more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another class to your button tag, e.g. `btn-custom` 
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success bottom-right btn-custom">Read more</button>`

Add the following inside your `@media (max-width: 768px)` block

```css
.btn-custom {
    position: static;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This will affect all my buttons.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to achieve the desired look without overwriting the `.bottom-right` class because it has absolute property. If you want to affect that button **only** you can specify a unique `class` or `id` to it and apply the CSS provided above.

Comment: Good idea. That seems to solve this. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class to your button tag like so

```
class="btn btn-success  bottom-right bottom-right-flex"
```

In your css for section @media (max-width: 768px)

add the following entry

```
.bottom-right.bottom-right-flex {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
 }
```

This tells it to only apply to the element **IF BOTH** bottom-right AND bottom-right-flex classes are present on the same element. This will help you define that specific element in that viewport without affecting your other elements while at the same time maintaining it's current css of bottom-right just  when your viewport is larger.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion. That could work pretty nice. I just tried your code here: http://vouzalis.dk/travis.html. The button is not going under the text `< 768px`?. Is that possible to solve?